# Magento: Bundled price is 0.00

Tags: magento

Magento v1.7.0.2
We've been using this version several years now.
We have several free and paid extensions and last month we created our first bundled product.
When in list view the price is shown as 'Start at 0,00' for some products.
Other bundles products are fine and show the correct minimum price.

I've been searching for a while now, but can't find a workable solution.
Here's a sample page: http://www.scrapwebshop.nl/kado-tip.html

Comment: Did you check your indexes are up-to-date? Especially Product Prices and Product Flat Data (if you use it). If it still doesn't work, try switching back to the base theme, and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: I just re-indexed. No change. How to change the theme? I can try that as well.

Comment: Still stuck with this issue.
I dumped $_product and in there minimal_price is already 0.00.

If anybody has some suggestions, please tell me. I'm running in circles right now.

Comment: Did you chosen the default simple or configurable product in bundle product admin configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. It is probably not the right nor most efficient way, but the result is what I need. And that is what counts ;)

I now I have a grouped product, so I loop through all associated products, put their prices in an array. Next I sort to get the lowest value on top and get the first array entry.
I hope it helps somebody else:

```
$associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product);
foreach ($associatedProducts as $assoc) {
  $prices[] = $assoc->price;
}
sort($prices, SORT_NUMERIC);
$_minimalPrice = array_shift($prices);  
$_exclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPrice);
$_inclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPrice, true)
```